# jQuery select column

Tags: jquery

I would like to select all cells of the first column of a table. Can anyone please tell me the code.

Tried this..

```
$('.sortable tr:nth-child(1)');    // getting entire row.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$('.sortable td:first-child');
```

Comment: mmm.... $('.sortable td:first-child'); would take all first td in class .sortable....

Comment: In my opinion, it is a good thing that th cells are not selected, as these are usually treated differently. Also, the OP mentioned nothing about th cells.

Comment: @ahmadali shafiee: See answer below (highest votes): $(".sortable tr > :nth-child(3)")

Comment: @kgiannakakis thanks. but that was the answer. but I wanted a way to select the third column of the table not just third column.

Answer (score 24):

This (fairly verbose) selector should work:

```
$(".sortable tr > :nth-child(1)")
```

If you want another column, simply change the index to `nth-child` to something other than `1`.

This will select both `td` (data) and `th` (header) cells, btw.

```js
$(".sortable tr > :nth-child(1)")
.css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<table class="sortable">
  <tr> <th>   A </th> <th>   B </th> <th>   C </th> </tr>
  <tr> <td>   1 </td> <td>   2 </td> <td>   3 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>  10 </td> <td>  20 </td> <td>  30 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> 100 </td> <td> 200 </td> <td> 300 </td> </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Considerably more verbose, but here's [my solution](https://gist.github.com/3209918) - a small jQuery-plugin that selects all the cells in a column of a table.

Comment: saved my life. Was searching for something like this for the last 2 hours. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.sortable tr td:first').each(function(){ 
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: I believe this will only select the very first cell of the table. Replacing `:first` with `:first-child` should give the expected result.