# Highlight first column in a row using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table, as I hover over the cells within the table the current cell and the first column is highlighted:

```
$('.price_cell').hover(function(){

    $(this).css('background-color','#cce6ff');
    $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).css({'background-color':'#0096E1','color':'#ffffff'});

},
function(){

    $(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).css({'background-color':'#ffffff','color':'#002436'});
});
```

This works fine.  However whilst I want the first column cells to change color as a user hovers over the cells on the line, I don't want the first column cells to change color when they are hovered over.

Comment: so you want the cell to change when the _row_ is hovered over, _unless_ it's the first cell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery select column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132034/jquery-select-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the index of the hovered cell, and change the CSS if the hovered cell isn't the first in the row:

```
$('.price_cell').hover(
    function() {
        if ($(this).index() != 0) {
            ...
        }
    },
    function() {
        if ($(this).index() != 0) {
            ...
        }
    }
);
```

or, potentially more efficient since it'll create a single pair of callbacks instead of registering a pair on every cell:

```
$('table')
    .delegate('.price_cell', 'mouseenter', function() {
        if ($(this).index() != 0) {
            // hover-in style here
        }
    })
    .delegate('.price_cell', 'mouseleave', function() {
        if ($(this).index() != 0) {
            // hover-out style here
        }
    });
```

NB: I'm not using `:not(:first-child)` here since that requires more work parsing the selector than the trivial `$(this).index()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with pure css.

```
table tr:hover                 { background-color: black; color:white;}
table tr:hover td:first-child  { background-color:white; color:black }
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/wBu5M/

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to:

```
$('.price_cell:not(:first-child)').hover(function(){
```

Using the delegate suggestion from Phrogz:

```
$('#mytable').delegate('.price_cell:not(:first-child)', 'mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#cce6ff');
    $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).css({'background-color':'#0096E1','color':'#ffffff'});

}).delegate('.price_cell:not(:first-child)', 'mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).css({'background-color':'#ffffff','color':'#002436'});
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that, except that both our answers end up potentially adding the same event to a lot of elements.

Comment: @Alnitak, Yes, it would be better to put the hover on the `tr` or the `table`. Absent the actual HTML there's not much room for improvement.

Comment: @Phrogz, yes, although that would appear to require a change to the single handler version of 'hover'. It doesn't appear that delegate version can handle separate hover-in / hover-out handlers.