# How can I get the corresponding table column (td) from a table header (th)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the entire column of a table header.

For example, I want to select the table header "Address" to hide the address column, and select the "Phone" header to show the correspondent column.

```
<table>
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th id="name">Name</th>
        <th id="address">Address</th>
        <th id="address" class='hidden'>Address</th>
    </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Freddy</td>
        <td>Nightmare Street</td>
        <td class='hidden'>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Luis</td>
        <td>Lost Street</td>
        <td class='hidden'>3456</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to do something like http://www.google.com/finance?q=apl (see the related companies table) *(click the "add or remove columns" link)*

Comment: isn't this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132034/jquery-select-column about the same issue?

Comment: i take it the 3rd column is the "Phone" column?

Comment: For coloring/shading a column instead of adding/removing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651408/how-can-apply-some-jquery-stuff-only-based-on-header-row

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work -

```
$('th').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index()+1;
    $('table td:nth-child(' + index + '),table th:nth-child(' + index + ')').hide()
});
```

The code above will hide the relevant column if you click on the header, the logic could be changed to suit your requirements though.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/LUDWQ/

Answer (score 1):

With a couple simple modifications to your HTML, I'd do something like the following (framework-less JS):

**HTML:**

```
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-index="0">Name</input>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-index="1">Address</input>
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-index="2">Phone</input>

<table id="tbl">
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead> 
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Freddy</td>
        <td>Nightmare Street</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Luis</td>
        <td>Lost Street</td>
        <td>3456</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var cb = document.getElementsByClassName("chk");
var cbsz = cb.length;

for(var n = 0; n < cbsz ; ++n) {
    cb[n].onclick = function(e) {
        var idx = e.target.getAttribute("data-index");
        toggleColumn(idx);
    }
}

function toggleColumn(idx) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var sz = rows.length;

    for(var n = 0; n < sz; ++n) {
        var el = n == 0 ? rows[n].getElementsByTagName("th")[idx] : rows[n].getElementsByTagName("td")[idx];
        el.style.display = el.style.display === "none" ? "table-cell" : "none";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/YqUNz/1/

I added the checkboxes as it doesn't make sense to bind the click to the column headers as you won't be able to toggle the visibility, only hide them.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I would guess it's because your answer is heavy, and because this question is tagged jquery but you answered with much heavier plain JS. For example the 'table-cell' fussiness problem is encapsulated nicely by $().hide(). However your answer is the most complete.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a class to each td that matches the class of the header. When you click the , it checks the class, then hides every td with that class. Since only the s in that column would hide that class, it would effectively hide the column.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td class="Name">Joe</td>
       <td class="Address">123 Main St.
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the script something like:

```
$('th').click( function() {
  var col = $(this).html(); // Get the content of the <th>
  $('.'+col).hide(); // Hide everything with a class that matches the col value.
});
```

Something like that, anyway. That's probably more verbose than it needs to be, but it should demonstrate the principle.

Another way would be to simply count how many columns over the  in question is, and then loop through each row and hide the td that is also that many columns over. For instance, if you want to hide the Address column and it is column #3 (index 2), then you would loop through each row and hide the third  (index 2).

Good luck..

Comment: Uh, how would you go about toggling the column's visibility `n` times rather than just hiding it?..

Comment: jQuery has a .toggle() function, which could be used instead of hide(). I was demonstrating how to hide a column. Bringing it back isn't much more difficult and follows the same basic principle.

Comment: Ah.. You know what? I misinterpreted your code (thought you were hiding the column header too, which made *no* sense ;)). Downvote removed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something with CSS, like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .c1 .c1, .c2 .c2, .c3 .c3{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="c2 c3">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th id="name" class="c1">Name</th>
            <th id="address" class="c2">Address</th>
            <th id="phone" class="c3">Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">Freddy</td>
            <td class="c2">Nightmare Street</td>
            <td class="c3">123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c1">Luis</td>
            <td class="c2">Lost Street</td>
            <td class="c3">3456</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

To hide a column, you add with Javascript the corresponding class to the table. Here c2 and c3 are hidden.

You could add dynamically the .c1, .c2,... in a style tag, or define a maximum number.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the Google Finance show/hide columns functionality:

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/HvA4s/

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
    var headers = $('#table th').map(function() {
        var th =  $(this);
        return {
            text: th.text(),
            shown: th.css('display') != 'none'
        };
    });

    var h = ['<div id=tableEditor><button id=done>Done</button><table><thead><tr>'];
    $.each(headers, function() {
        h.push('<th><input type=checkbox',
               (this.shown ? ' checked ' : ' '),
               '/> ',
               this.text,
               '</th>');
    });
    h.push('</tr></thead></table></div>');
    $('body').append(h.join(''));

    $('#done').click(function() {
        var showHeaders = $('#tableEditor input').map(function() { return this.checked; });
        $.each(showHeaders, function(i, show) {
            var cssIndex = i + 1;
            var tags = $('#table th:nth-child(' + cssIndex + '), #table td:nth-child(' + cssIndex + ')');
            if (show)
                tags.show();
            else
                tags.hide();
        });

        $('#tableEditor').remove();
        return false;
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('thead td').click( function () {

    var th_index = jQuery(this).index();

    jQuery('#my_table tbody tr').each(
        function(index) {
            jQuery(this).children('td:eq(' + th_index + ');').each(
                function(index) {
                    // do stuff here
                }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

here's a working fiddle of this behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/tycRW/

of course, hiding the column with out hiding the header for it will have some strange results.