# How can I apply some jquery stuff only based on header row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have the table like this:

```
<table> 
<thead>
   <th>id </th><th>name </th><th>number </th><th>result </th> 
</thead>        
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>stuff</td>
 <td>stuff</td>
 <td>stuff</td>
 <td>stuff</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

I want to add the `class = "red"` only to those `td` whose header is `result`

so only result column with jquery dynamically when page loads.

Comment: I'm going to be that jerk on Stackoverflow that asks why you want to do this: is this table static, or does it load from a data source? If it loads from a data source, the class you mentioned should really be in the template; if you're not using templates, you should use a system that lets you use templates, like angularjs.org. If it's static, the answers here are the right ones.

Comment: For adding/removing a column instead of coloring it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142892/how-can-i-get-the-corresponding-table-column-td-from-a-table-header-th?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index of the header using [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) then apply the class using the [`:nth-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hgJU/)

[image]

```
var resultHeaderIndex = $('th:contains("result")').index();
$('td:nth-child(' + (resultHeaderIndex + 1) + ')').addClass('red')
```

---

If you wanted to add the class to the header also then you can simply add it before you get the index:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ukB6/1/)

[image]

```
var resultHeaderIndex = $('th:contains("result")')
    .addClass('red')
    .index();
$('td:nth-child(' + (resultHeaderIndex + 1) + ')').addClass('red')
```

Comment: That reminded me! Easier way to do it: `$('th:contains("result")').addClass('red')`

Comment: This doesn't color the whole column, just the lower cells. Color the header as well

Comment: @PitaJ the question states "I want to add the class = "red" only to those td whose header is result"

Comment: Ok I think he means to include the header, though

Comment: +1 for short code. PitaJ's objection is easily resolved with ... = $('th:contains("result")').addClass('red').index();

Answer (score 1):

I think using jQuery `.index()` and `.eq()` you could do this pretty easily:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.colorColumn = function(headerText, color){
        var index = this.find("th").filter(function(){
            return ($(this).text() == headerText);
        }).css("backgroundColor", color).index();
        this.find("tr").each(function(){
            $(this).children().eq(index).css({backgroundColor: color});
        })
    }
})(jQuery);

$("table").colorColumn("number", "red");
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pitaj/eG5KE/

Comment: i looked at your website pitaz and it gave me error in database connction :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is use a conditional and jQuery `each`:

```
$("th").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "result") { $(this).addClass('red') }
}
```